# Client certificate authentication with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication, certificate, client

I'm using a WCF Service which is configured to require an client certificate to allow client connections. I tested everything with postman and the service just works fine. It just comes to problems, if I try to authenticate with an flutter client. Of course I'm using https.

I tried with

```
var clientCertificate = (await rootBundle.load('lib/assets/certificates/clientAuthenticationCert.pfx')).buffer.asInt8List();
securityContext.useCertificateChainBytes(clientCertificate, password: "test");
securityContext.usePrivateKeyBytes(clientCertificate, password: "test");
HttpClient httpsClient = HttpClient(context: securityContext);
IOClient httpTest = new IOClient(httpsClient);
http.Response response = await httpTest.post(kIsWeb ? Uri.parse(_serviceEndpointWithProxy) : Uri.parse(_ServiceEndpoint),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
      "SOAPAction": "http://someUrl/someService/${action}",
      "Host": "someService.someUrl.net",
      "Accept": "*/*",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
      "Content-Length": utf8.encode(envelope).length.toString(),
    },
    body: envelope,
    encoding: Encoding.getByName("utf-8"));
```

But unfortunately it thorws an exception without any further details.

Any idear how to use client certificate authentication with flutter?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Any idea what the exception says? Or where it is thrown? (You cannot use IOClient on web of course.) Set up a plain Dart project (no Flutter) with just a `main()` and try it there. You should get some decent error output that way. Update the question with the results.

Comment: Also, when you construct the contect be sure to add the trusted roots: `SecurityContext(withTrustedRoots: true)`

Comment: minimal main as follows: `import 'dart:io';

import 'package:http/io_client.dart' as ioh;

void main() async {
  final pfx = File(pfxPath).readAsBytesSync();
  final context = SecurityContext(withTrustedRoots: true)
    ..useCertificateChainBytes(pfx, password: pwd)
    ..usePrivateKeyBytes(pfx, password: pwd);

  final ioClient = ioh.IOClient(HttpClient(context: context));
  final response = await ioClient.get(url);
  print(response.statusCode);
}`