# How to extract the private key from .pfx file using flutter dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, digital-signature, private-key, pfx

I have a base64 string then i convert it to byte and save it as file.pfx in some directory in my mac, this file can only open by password that i have already, So how to extract the private key from this file using flutter and dart?

I tride many of pkgs like rsa_pkcs and others and nothing give me what i need (private key)

Comment: If the *.pfx is protected, you need the password to extract the key. No way around

Comment: I have the password but how to extract the key

Comment: check this answer here. They are using SecurityContext https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68665400/client-certificate-authentication-with-flutter

final context = SecurityContext(withTrustedRoots: true)
        ..useCertificateChainBytes(pfx, password: pwd)
        ..usePrivateKeyBytes(pfx, password: pwd);

Comment: Or, since you have the file, you can rely on your os and launch the command from flutter dart 

`openssl pkcs12 -in file.pfx -nocerts -nodes -out test.key -pass pass:somepassword`

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.4/dart-io/Process/run.html

Comment: Yes, it would be great. I also need to do just that.